# KendoUI Upload Control not posting correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor, file-upload, kendo-ui

Using VS'12 KendoUI - C# asp.net MVC EF Code First Internet Application Template

- I have finally gotten my Kendo DDL ( DropDownList ) to work,

  I was working on the post ActionResult when I found that

  `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is Always `false` when I click on My *kendoUI Upload button* ( the one bound in the control)

[image]

- If however i click on the Regular submitt button `<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="do" class="k-button"/>` the `ModelState.IsValid` is true, but **none** of my "Upload selected files" were in the `[Httppost]` `actionResult`

***My Question is simple , how do i Post both of them to my Controller at once?***

> here is a little example of my code ( the 2 buttons )

```
<div>    
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="do" class="k-button"/>
    </p>
</div>

@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("attachments")
        .Async(async => async
            .Save("Index", "ImageUpload")
            .AutoUpload(false)
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configured your upload control to upload files asynchronously; therefore, it doesn't POST *with* the form. If you want *both* your form data and your files to POST at the same time to the same controller, then you need to configure your upload control to be synchronous, not Async, and you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form/>` tag. Then in your MVC controller, make sure one of your parameters is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments` along with your form data model parameter(s).

Comment: Found the answer here thanks for the push in the right direction! http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/index.html